# Mysql ordenando por valor especifico porêm retornando todos valores

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde,
Existe algum método de em uma consulta sql ordenar apartir de um valor e se existir esse valor retornar ele de primeiro e depois todo resto dos valores ?

Exemplo : Uma tabela com dias do 1 a 7, onde eu colocaria pra caso existisse retornasse o valor 5 primeiro e depois todos os outros ( "123467")

Seria quase um **where** mas que eu conseguisse puxar os outros valores também após esse valor selecionado.

```
        $dia =  5;

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tabela where dia = $dia");

       //Teria que retornar query com o primeiro valor = 5 e depois todos outros valores.
```

Comment: É só fazer um `ORDER BY dia != 5, dia`, no seu caso, `ORDER BY dia != $dia, dia`. Qualquer coisa que fuja disso, complica à toa e ainda corre o risco de não aproveitar os índices. A explicação está no post original linkado acima (atenção para o `!=`, que é pelo false ser ordenado como menor que true). Se quiser, faça um SQL FIDDLE com alguns dados de exemplo, que eu demonstro a query pra você.

Comment: Aliás, eu já tinha feito um fiddle em 2016, nem lembrava (está no post original). Teste aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52a4c3/1 - A diferença do exemplo lá é que como segundo critério estamos usando outro campo.

Comment: Obrigado @Bacco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que o registro deva ter prioridade sobre os outros valores e estar em primeiro lugar pode usar [MySQL `FIELD` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_field).

```
SELECT * FROM tabela ORDER BY FIELD(dia, $dia) DESC, dia ASC"
```

Definimos o `$dia` com prioridade ou mais relevância através da instrução `ORDER BY FIELD(dia, $dia) DESC`

[**Fonte**](http://pedroelsner.com/2011/10/ordenando-resultados-especificos-no-mysql/)

Outra forma: [MySQL `CASE` function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp).

```
select * from tabela order by case when dia = $dia then 1 else 2 end, dia
```

> Especialmente no MySQL, você também pode fazer

```
select * from tabela order by dia <> $dia,  dia
```

> Uma vez que o resultado de uma comparação no MySQL é  `0` ou `1` você pode classificar por esse resultado. [Not equal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal)

Answer (score -1):

Faça duas consultas e use os resultados na sequência:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela where dia = $dia"
SELECT * FROM tabela where dia <> $dia"
```

***"Ah, mas eu não quero fazer duas consultas..."***

Então una os resultados das duas consultas em um só, ordene pelo campo que você quer e faça a consulta sobre esse resultado.

```
SELECT resultado.dia, ordem -- outros campos
  FROM (
       SELECT dia, 1 as ordem -- outros campos
         FROM tabela where dia = 5
       UNION
       SELECT dia, concat(2, dia) as ordem -- outros campos
         FROM tabela where dia <> 5 
     ORDER BY dia
  ) as resultado
ORDER BY ordem
```

Comment: Lembrando ao glorioso *downvoter* que essa é a única resposta que não usa funções específicas do MySQL, ou seja, se alguém chegar até esta pergunta com o mesmo problema (inclusive o próprio autor) e quiser fazer a mesma coisa, só que em outro BD, a solução com SQL standard é a única que funciona.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira, pense que tenho uma tabela com o nome `teste` e seus campos `id` e `nome`, você pode  usar o `ORDER BY FIELD` do MySQL e sua consulta ficaria assim:

```
SELECT
   id,
   nome
FROM teste
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 3) DESC;
```

onde o resultado seria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acho que é isso que precisa.

Abraço